# Webpack resolve path using alias to drive root

Tags: angular, typescript, path, webpack, resolve

how could i use aliases in webpack to address files in another drive:

it's my web pack resolve method:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    Hma: 'D:/GitHub/Hma.Components/src/app'
  },
  extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json']
  ,modules: [helpers.root('src'), helpers.root('node_modules')]
}
```